# i am new to Lightning. I am not able to insert records in contact object

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, lightning-apps

```
My Apex Controller
--------------------
public class CreateContactRecord {

    @AuraEnabled
    public static void CreateRecord(Contact Contact ){

        try{
            if(Contact  !=null){
                insert Contact ;
            }
        } catch(exception ex){

        }

    }
}
 Component
 -----------
 <aura:component controller="CreateContactRecord">
     <aura:attribute name="contacts" type="Contact[]"/>
    <aura:attribute name="Contact" type="Contact" default="{'sobjectType':'Contact','FirstName':'','LastName':''}"/>
    <aura:attribute name="isOpen" type="boolean" default="false"/>
    <div class="slds-m-around--xx-large">
        <button class="slds-button slds-button--brand" onclick="{!c.openModel}">New</button>
        <aura:if isTrue="{!v.isOpen}">

   <!--###### MODAL BOX Start From Here ######--> 
      <div role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="header99" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open ">
        <div class="slds-modal__container">
          <!-- ###### MODAL BOX HEADER Part Start From Here ######-->
          <div class="slds-modal__header">
            <button class="slds-button slds-modal__close slds-button--icon-inverse" title="Close" onclick="{!c.closeModel}">
            X
            <span class="slds-assistive-text">Close</span>
            </button>
            <h2 id="header99" class="slds-text-heading--medium">Insert New Contact</h2>
          </div>
          <!--###### MODAL BOX BODY Part Start From Here ######-->
          <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around--medium">
            <div class="form-group">
            <label>First Name</label>
            <ui:inputText class="form-control" value="{!v.Contact.FirstName}"/>
              </div><br/>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Last Name</label>
            <ui:inputText class="form-control" value="{!v.Contact.LastName}"/>
        </div>
          </div>
          <!--###### MODAL BOX FOOTER Part Start From Here ######-->
          <div class="slds-modal__footer">


            <ui:button class="uiButton" press="{!c.closeModel}">Cancel</ui:button>

              <ui:button class="uiButton" press="{!c.create}">Create</ui:button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop--open"></div>
      <!--###### MODAL BOX Part END Here ######-->

 </aura:if>
    </div>
</aura:component>
--------------------------
Conponent Controller
------------------
({
    openModel: function(component, event, helper) {
      // for Display Model,set the "isOpen" attribute to "true"
      component.set("v.isOpen", true);
   },

   closeModel: function(component, event, helper) {
      // for Hide/Close Model,set the "isOpen" attribute to "Fasle"  
      component.set("v.isOpen", false);
   },
    create:function(component, event, helper){
        var Contact  = component.get("v.Contact");
        if($A.util.isEmpty(Contact.FirstName) || $A.util.isUndefined(Contact.FirstName)){
            alert('First Name is Required');
            return;
        }            
        if($A.util.isEmpty(Contact.LastName) || $A.util.isUndefined(Contact.LastName)){
            alert('Last Name is Rqquired');
            return;
        }

        var action = component.get("c.CreateRecord");

        //Setting the Apex Parameter
        action.setParams({
            con : Contact
        });

        action.setCallback(this,function(a){
            //get the response state
            var state = a.getState();

            //check if result is successfull
            if(state == "SUCCESS"){
                //Reset Form
                var newCandidate = {'sobjectType': 'Contacts',
                                    'FirstName': '',
                                    'LastName': ''

                                   };
                //resetting the Values in the form
                component.set("v.candidate",newCandidate);
                alert('Record is Created Successfully');
            } else if(state == "ERROR"){
                alert('Error in calling server side action');
            }
        });

        //adds the server-side action to the queue        
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
      component.set("v.isOpen", false);
    }
})
```

Comment: And what happens? Errors? Did you review debug log? Help will be much faster if you tell us what is going on

Comment: i am not getting any error. but record not insert in contact Object

Comment: field validation every thing working fine. when i am click create button it's showing "record successfully" inserted but record not insert in object

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your javascript:

```
action.setParams({
        con : Contact
    });
```

is not correct, the param name must match param in Apex and it should be:

```
action.setParams({
        "Contact" : Contact
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

**Never** write an empty `catch` block like this as you are hiding error conditions making it much harder to debug your code and find errors in UAT or production orgs:

```
    try{
        if(Contact  !=null){
            insert Contact ;
        }
    } catch(exception ex){

    }
```

At a minimum in `@AuraEnabled` methods use this:

```
    try {
        insert contact;
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        throw new AuraHandledException(ex.getMessage());
    }
```

that will [return an error to the client-side](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_apex_custom_errors.htm?search_text=AuraHandledException).

Answer (score -1):

**Apex class**

```
public class CreateContactcls {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static string createContact(Contact contObj){
        system.debug('CONTACT@@'+contObj.FirstName);
        insert contObj;
        return contObj.Id;
    }
}
```

**AURA COMPONENT**

```
<aura:component controller="CreateContactcls" implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" >
     
<aura:attribute name="contactObj" type="contact" default={'sobjectType': 
                                                             'contact',
                                                             'FirstName':'',
                                                              'LastName':'',
                                                              'Phone':''}"/>
  <aura:attribute name="contactId" type="String"/>
 <lightning:input  label="First name" value="{!v.contactObj.FirstName}"placeholder="Enter First name.." required="true"/>

<lightning:input label="Last name" value="{!v.contactObj.LastName}"placeholder="Enter Last name..." />
 
<lightning:input label="Phone" value="{!v.contactObj.Phone}"placeholder="Enter phone number.." />
 
<lightning:button variant="success" label="Save" title="Save" onclick="{!c.handleClick }"/>
</aura:component>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
({              
    handleClick : function(component, event, helper) { 
        var action = component.get("c.createContact");
        var postdata =component.get('v.contactObj');
        action.setParams({'contObj':postdata});
        alert(JSON.stringify(postdata));
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") 
            {
                component.set('v.contactId',response.getReturnValue());
                alert('DATA@@'+JSON.stringify(response.getReturnValue()));
            }
        });
      
            var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
            toastEvent.setParams({
                "title": "Success!",
                "message": "The record has been updated successfully."
            });
            toastEvent.fire();
        
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I've downvoted this answer because it is a _code dump_ (all code, no explanation about why it works or how it solves the issue).